# Best libraries, extras and things for C# (ASP.NET included)

Tags: c#, ide

I wanted to know what would some good libraries, IDE's, extras, for C# (include web development in ASP.NET be) for example:

### Libraries

- *[Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Start)* - Cross platform C#.Net implementation, also able to run ASP.NET specific stuff

### IDE's

- *[Sharp Develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/)* - OpenSource C# IDE (Includes compiler)
- *[MonoDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/)* - OpenSource and cross platform C# IDE (Includes compiler)

### Extras

- *[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html)* - Unit testing and code refactoring for C# (Free for OpenSource)
- *[.Net Memory Profilie (Not free)](http://memprofiler.com/)* - Name says it all, not free for any use
- *[Refactor!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb693327.aspx)* - Refactoring for C#

Thanks

Comment: If i can get enough answers, it would be great to make this a comunity wiki xD will continue to vote up good answers and add them to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Reflector
- Process Explorer (not .NET specific, but a definite must have)
- Linq Pad
- Wire Shark (not .NET specific, but should be in every Dev's toolkit)

Comment: Wins for beign the best list xD

Answer (score 4):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html) is one of the best "extras" I've come across.

Comment: Installing it now, great addition

Answer (score 0):

For .NET libraries, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662956/most-useful-free-net-libraries) is comprehensive. As for IDE's, I use either Visual Studio, the [VS Express Editions](http://www.microsoft.com/exPress/) or [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **Visual Studio 2008** with i.e. the [Refactor! 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb693327.aspx) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

**Libraries**

here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662956/most-useful-free-net-libraries

Answer (score 0):

Html Agility pack:
http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack

Mixed with linq, gives you a flexible htmlparser(webpage scraper):
http://web.archive.org/web/20080719181517/vijay.screamingpens.com/archive/2008/05/26/linq-amp-lambda-part-3-html-agility-pack-to-linq.aspx

Comment: This will be hard to add, but will do